# Select div having similar class name but no div id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Parent Class `inddetails-wrapper clearfix` has two divs which as further classes having same name.
I want to select first class `col-md-6 nopadding`. How should I do that ?

Below is the code:

```
<div class="inddetails-wrapper clearfix">
    <div>
        <div class="col-md-6 nopadding">...</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="col-md-6 nopadding">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe this can help you (https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp)[first child]

Comment: @Sfili_81 Don't direct users to W3Schools, better ones are MDN and Web Content Platform. Please encourage that. `:)`

Comment: ok sorry, i know mdn is better (i'll use too) but forgive me, i wake up right now :(

Comment: @Sfili_81 Sure... `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `:first-child`:

```css
.inddetails-wrapper div:first-child .col-md-6 {
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="inddetails-wrapper clearfix">
  <div>
    <div class="col-md-6 nopadding">...</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="col-md-6 nopadding">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, yeah got it:  $(".inddetails-wrapper.clearfix > div:first-child > .col-md-6.nopadding");

Comment: @AmbikaTewari You're welcome! `:)` And you don't need `>` in this case, at least.

Answer (score 0):

as this question was tagged under jquery You can select the first element inside `<div class="inddetails-wrapper clearfix">` using Jquery like this:

```
var firstChild = $( ".inddetails-wrapper.clearfix div" ).first();
```

and you can play with `firstChild` using more jquery properties depending upon what do you need.